# styling alternating rows in a table

Tags: css, css-selectors

is it possible to set the style of alternating rows in a html table with style selectors that only take account of the hierarchy of elements and do not use style names?

i need to style html output produced by a server component and the output does not set styles for alternating rows. i could write a javascript (or just as well change the component) but i am curious about whether it is possible to do in pure css.

thanks
konstantin

Comment: depends what kind of server component generates it

Comment: related : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/474216/what-is-the-best-way-to-style-alternating-rows-in-a-table

Comment: @KennyTM: it needs to work in IE6, so i guess it is not possible without javascript, but my question is a general one so i would be interested to learn how to do this in both css2 and css3.

Comment: +1 Thanks for asking this question, this helped me out! =)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

In CSS 3:

```
tr:nth-child(odd)    { background-color:#eee; }
tr:nth-child(even)    { background-color:#fff; }
```

And in CSS 2, you have to use some class on e.g. even rows like:

```
.even { background-color: #00000; }
```

and you have to apply them when generating the rows server-side (or in hand ;-) ) or with e.g. jQuery like:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("tr.nth-child(even)").addClass("even");
    //Or
    $("tr:even").addClass("even");
});
```

Comment: Now days update: as posted [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/11222732/1207195) you can use [selectivizr](http://selectivizr.com/) to emulate CSS3 selectors on IE6-8 (your CSSs will work with that versions and browsers with good support won't be polluted by tricks for IE)