# Different CSS style on odd and even rows

Tags: javascript, css-tables

Is it possible, using only CSS, to set different styles on odd and even rows for a dynamically generated table without myself setting correct style on each row when I iterate the collection?

Comment: See here for a demonstration of the `nth-child` answers: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5080699/using-css-even-and-odd-pseudo-selectors-with-list-items

Comment: You shouldn't confuse Java and JavaScript (it was retagged for you). See: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/245062/whats-the-difference-between-javascript-and-java

Comment: +1 for jQuery, it exists for a reason, and there really is not any valid reasons not to use it if you are using JavaScript to begin with.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I'm not sure this will work cross-browser, i'd prefer jQuery myself, but css-only this should do the trick:

```
tr:nth-child(even) { ... }
tr:nth-child(odd) { ... }
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use the `nth-child` selector http://reference.sitepoint.com/css/pseudoclass-nthchild, though it is not supported by all browsers.

You can also use jquery as described [What is the best way to style alternating rows in a table?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/474216/what-is-the-best-way-to-style-alternating-rows-in-a-table)

Answer (score 2):

You can do this with CSS3.

```
tr:nth-child(2n+1) /* targets all odd rows */
tr:nth-child(2n) /* targets all even rows */
```

Answer (score 1):

you can simply use jquery and add class for odd rows like

```
$("tr:nth-child(odd)").addClass("odd");
```

and style it using css as

```
.odd{background-color:#657383}
```