# Styling alternate blockquotes with different colors

Tags: css, stylesheet

I have the following  code. I want to have different background color for blockquotes having innertext Text2 & Text4, and different background for blockquotes having innertext Text1 & Text3. Need help.

```
<div class="quotes">
<blockquote>Text1</blockquote>
<blockquote>Text2</blockquote>
<blockquote>Text3</blockquote>
<blockquote>Text4</blockquote>
</div>
```

Comment: It's not possible to match text in CSS3, can you use javascript ?

Comment: don't want to match content. Just want to have different backgrounds for even and odd blockquotes.

Comment: In that case edit your question because you did say you wanted to match inner text

Comment: I just have given the example.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Different CSS style on odd and even rows](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5096433/different-css-style-on-odd-and-even-rows)

Comment: @CodyGray no, its different.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [nth-child selector](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:nth-child):

Ex-

```
blockquote:nth-child(1){ /*for first blockquote */
  background-color: red;
}
blockquote:nth-child(2){ /*for second blockquote */
   background-color: red;
}
```

---

As per your comment:

You can use odd and even too:

```
blockquote:nth-child(odd){
   background-color: red;
}


blockquote:nth-child(even){
   background-color: red;
}
```

Comment: can i do this while using in-line style to div? and there can be multiple blockquotes.

Comment: I am doing this in wordpress and my actual code is something like this:<style>
.test blockquote:odd{
   background-color: red;
}


.test blockquote:even{
   background-color: green;
}
</style>

<div class="test">
[li_recommendations width="480" length="200" interval="1000"]
</div>

Comment: and there are coming blockquote in [li_recommendations width="480" length="200" interval="1000"]. Now I want to show alternate blockquote with different background colors

Comment: so there will be only 2 colors or 3 colors?

Comment: Yes there will be only 2 colors.

Comment: I might be inclined to use `nth-of-type` over `nth-of-child` for added comfort just in case of intervening elements.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
blockquote:nth-child(even){
  background-color: red;
}
blockquote:nth-child(odd){
   background-color: blue;
}
```

Comment: Yes but it will give alternate color.